# Error while trying to import SpeechRecognition module in Atom text editor

Tags: python, linux, speech-recognition

I'm having an issue importing the SpeechRecognition module installed with pip3 in the Atom text editor even though it works in the terminal. I'm using the latest Kali Linux distribution at the time of this post, and lastly it's being run in Python 3.

I've tried running it all within the same anaconda virtual environment to no avail, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling the module

```
import speech_recognition as sr
```

I expected the module to import, but i get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'`.

Comment: How are you running your python script?  Do you run it from within Atom?  What version of Python is Atom using?

Comment: I am running python 3.8.1, and I am running the script inside atom